# Setup Project not capturing updates

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-project

This is my first dabble into Setup Projects.
I have Solution in VS2013.
Within the solution is a C# Winform project, and a Setup Project.

On first build, I can use the setup.exe to install my application on my laptop; no issues.
However, when I make changes to my Winforms, these are not reflected by any subsequent re-install.
Quite simply, the build does not pass winform changes to the setup package.

To explain:
I make changes to a form, for example I add a label or button.
In my setup project I increase the version number.
VS automatically generates a new Product Code.
Build all.
Copy the setup.exe + msi from the setup project's debug folder.
Paste to desktop.
Execute setup.exe
Install completes successfully.
Control Panel > Programs, confirms the new version number.
Yet running the app, none of my form changes are there !?

Hope someone might be able to explain what's going on, what I am missing !?
Many Thanks

Comment: The question is what kind of setup tool you're using. As VS2013 doesn't contain the old "Setup Project" anymore it must either be WiX or the light version of InstallShield. Then, the question is how you reference the files you want to install. Maybe you copied a version to your setup project that gets packaged every time but is not up to date? Please check whether your setup actually references the current build of your executable and dependencies.

Comment: So the setup project is 'Visual Studio Installer'.

As for 'references the current build of your executable'; that where I am a little lost.
From the Startup project I map the target machine's Application folder to 'Primary output from <project> (Active)'.

Obviously on the first build, it is finding the correct files to build the setup.exe/msi.
I 'assumed' that it would then automaticaly pick up changes next build.

Comment: It does not come with VS2013 out of the box; but it's still available to instal

Comment: See, you learn something new every day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Visual Studio Installer project will automatically pick up the right version of the application if you add the Primary Output of your application. So that's that.

It could be that Visual Studio **does** package the new version of the executable, but it does **not get installed**, because you forgot to increase the executable's version number, too (not just the installer's version number!). AFAIK, Windows Installer replaces files only if the version number differs.

What happens when you uninstall the old version before installing the new version? Do you then see your changes? If that's the case, try increasing the version number before the next update.

Comment: So if I uninstall the existing, the new does install perfectly. So the Setup package DOES contain all the new build.   Now I am MORE confused what happens when I install over an exsting installation,  As I said previously, the version number is increased, and windows confirm that that the newl install has the new Vsn number.  And yet the forms themselves have not changed !?

Comment: You say `In my setup project I increase the version number`. That is **not the same** as increasing the executable's version number! **Do that and try again**. It doesn't matter what Control Panel shows. Check the version number of the executable in your installation folder by right clicking and selecting "Properties". I suspect the new version of the exe does not get copied because Windows Installer **thinks it is the same version**.

Comment: Ahhhhh.. now we have it !   Thorsten, you are a wonderfully patient man, thank you.

Comment: In summary, when I make updates, I must update the Assembly/file version numbers of my winform project AND the version number in my setup project.  Seemed 'illogical'  to me, to have to maintain the vsn in 2 separate places, but I guess I should go off any read up more about the 'why' behind it all. I'm sure it will all become clear now I know where to look.  Once again, thank you :)

Comment: The installer version is simply an indication that an update should be performed if the product was previously installed. The assembly version is used to determine the changes in case of an update.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not AssemblyVersion. It's just that if there is no explicit file version then it will default to AssemblyVersion. But changing AssemblyVersion can affect clients that require a specific AssemblyVersion. So just specify AssemblyFileVersion, increment it, leaving AssemblyVersion alone.

Answer (score 0):

Change all version numbers of your **hosted application** in AssemblyInfo.cs together with **Version** number and **Product code** in your installer (Setup project).